# finding a matrix $A$ for a change of variables that transforms one PDE into another PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose I have the PDE:

$3f_{x_1x_1} + 3f_{x_1x_2} + 3f_{x_2x_2} = 0$

And I want to transform this PDE into:

$\alpha_1f_{z_1z_1} + \alpha_2f_{z_2z_2} = 0$

where $(z_1, z_2)^T = A(x_1, x_2)^T$

How can I figure out the matrix $A$ that will accomplish the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

It's an elliptic equation so it's posible write it in its canonical form with a suitable variable change. Following the general idea [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_partial_differential_equation#Derivation_of_Canonical_Form) I've found the following new variables (constant coefficients help :):

$$z_1=x_1-x_2$$
$$z_2=\frac{x_1}{\sqrt 3}+\frac{x_2}{\sqrt 3}$$

And in matrix notation
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
z_1\\
z_2
\end{matrix}\right)
=
\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & -1\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt 3} & \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}
\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{matrix}\right)$$

I've tried to find a more, so said, simetric transformation without success. Anyway, we obtain the two dimension Laplace equation:

$$f_{z_1z_1}+f_{z_2z_2}=0$$

So, if you wish $\alpha_1f_{z_1z_1}+\alpha_2f_{z_2z_2}=0$ you only need to rescale the variables:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
z_1\\
z_2
\end{matrix}\right)
=
\left(\begin{matrix}
\sqrt\alpha_1 & 0\\
0 & \sqrt\alpha_2
\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & -1\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt 3} & \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}
\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{matrix}\right)$$
So:
$$A=
\left(\begin{matrix}
\sqrt\alpha_1 & -\sqrt\alpha_1\\
\frac{\sqrt\alpha_2}{\sqrt 3} & \frac{\sqrt\alpha_2}{\sqrt 3}
\end{matrix}\right)$$